NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source, even after setting up Personal Access Token
Recently my Net7 build pipeline started failing with the error
NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<mypartner>/<guid>/_packaging/mypackagename/nuget/v3/index.json

I can open the index.json in the browser in a round about manner.
In that on navigating to the .json Microsoft asks me to login again.
I then get a 404 error

This pkgs.dev.azure.com page cant be found  No web page was found for
the web address  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/_public/_MsalSignedIn 
HTTP ERROR 404

If I then refresh I do see the .json
My Yaml is
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
  ValidAuthenticationTypes_trackCommon: 'negotiate,ntlm'

steps:
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: 'trackCommon'
    forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true


- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=6.1'
    checkLatest: false
    
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PAV_NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN]$(PAV_NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN)"
  displayName: 'Set NuGet Auth Token'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'ApiFortrack/nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'trackCommon'
 

The error occurs on the last task DotNetCoreCLI@2
I tried adding a Personal Access Token to the mypartner organization as per Zimmergren.net but it has not helped.
I use the same email address to login to the devops organisation that my pipeline is in and the mypartner organization. I wonder if it is relevant that I have to authenticate each time I switch between these organisations.
Update
After reading this similar question I tried replacing the problem task with
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'ApiFortrack/nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'trackCommon'

However the pipeline does not complete this task. After 25 minutes I cancelled and am now trying a re-run.
The log says
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\6.11.0\x64\nuget.exe restore D:\a\1\s\ApiFortrack3.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile D:\a\1\s\ApiFortrack\nuget.config

Update
I was able to get the pipeline running by updating the PAT in the trackCommon service connection.
Now I am wondering whether adding the PAT in a variable is redundant.
Also I am wondering if moving the mypartner organisation to be in the same Entre Id Tenant as my source project would remove the need for a PAT.  I gather it would save the constant need to authenticate as I switch between organisations.

The PAT needed to be set up in the Service Connection

Hi @Kirsten, Good day. Would you consider the query in this post is resolved? Thx for your time and sharing.

Thans Aguy I accepted my answer

Based on your update and the test from my side, you don't have to connect your partner's organization to be in the same Microsoft Entra Id. The NuGetCommand@2 task will authenticate assess to external Azure DevOps organization feed against the PAT from the NuGet service connection, which is generated to the scope of the external organization.
Besides, if both of your organizations are backed with the same Micrsoft Entra Id, you may consider Using packages from feeds in other organizations associated with your Microsoft Entra tenant to avoid the issue caused by PAT expiration and risk of PAT leakage.

